# How can I invalidate old log in cookie in asp.net identity (forms authentication)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Our company has an old web forms site running. The problem we had was that in web.config the expiration of log in cookie was originally set for a year for some odd reason...  We decided to change that to 7 days now.

So I updated the timeout value in web.config.  That part is fine.. But the problem is that for users who had logged in before this update and if they had the remember me check box checked.. they are still able to log in with the old cookie.

Is there a way I can force everyone to log in again?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the name of the Cookie in the web.config file, the data does not match the one stored on the local computer and the user is invalid and will be required to login again.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="myNewCookieName" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: is this the only option?  Why doesn't it automatically invalidate all the old cookies since I changed the how long the cookie is valid for...

Comment: Because all the cookie data is stored client side. The server just checks the credentials and expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, You Can Try This. If It Can Help. [I just Found it on the internet so if it can help you](https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/close-kill-all-active-database.html)

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for me because i don't have the access to do that.  Why doesn't asp.net already invalidate all old cookies if i make a change like that to the cookie expiration date?